# C++ templates: return value by type

Tags: c++, templates

I'm learning C++ and templates to implement a configuration file reader (http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/chameleon.html) and I’m trying to make a template for a class with a `std::string` as internal storage, which can return its internal value when assigning it to a variable (double, long double, float, string, uint16_t, uint32_t).

Platform: Win10 with Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 1

```
class HybridType {
public:
    HybridType() {};
    explicit HybridType(const std::string& value) : internalStr(value) {}
    explicit HybridType(const char* value) : internalStr (std::string(value)) { }

    template<typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type>
    explicit HybridType(T numericValue) {
        std::stringstream strstr;
        strstr << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10 + 1) << numericValue;
        internalStr = strstr.str();
    }

    operator std::string() const { return internalStr; }

    template<typename T>
    operator T() const {
        if (std::is_same<T, std::uint16_t>::value) return std::stoi(internalStr);
        if (std::is_same<T, std::uint32_t>::value) return std::stoul(internalStr);
        if (std::is_same<T, std::uint64_t>::value) return std::stoul(internalStr);
        if (std::is_same<T, double>::value) return std::stod(internalStr);
        if (std::is_same<T, long double>::value) return std::stold(internalStr);
        if (std::is_same<T, float>::value) return std::stof(internalStr);
        return std::stoll(internalStr);
    }



    template<typename T> operator T*() { return internalStr.c_str(); }

private:
    std::string internalStr;
};
```

When using it, I do the following:

```
uint32_t test = HybridType("50");
long double test2 = HybridType("50.0");
```

But when I compile this, I get a lot of warnings:

```
1> warning C4244: 'return': conversion from 'double' to 'uint32_t',
possible loss of data 1>  see reference to function template
instantiation 'HybridType::operator T(void) const<uint32_t>' being
compiled 1>          with 1>          [ 1>              T=uint32_t 1> ] 
1> warning C4244: 'return': conversion from 'long double' to
'uint32_t', possible loss of data 1> warning C4244: 'return':
conversion from 'float' to 'uint32_t', possible loss of data 1>
warning C4244: 'return': conversion from '__int64' to 'uint32_t',
possible loss of data
```

I didn’t really understand why I have these warnings (compiler cannot choose the appropriate type), because when I output my variables they seem to have the correct value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Templates are evaluated at compile time, thus you can't use `if()` to select the appropriate conversion function at runtime (return types will conflict, hence the warnings).

You need to provide type specialized implementations for your cast operator instead:

```
class HybridType {
public:
    // ...
    template<typename T>
    operator T() const {
        static_assert(std::is_same<T, std::uint16_t>::value ||
                      std::is_same<T, std::uint32_t>::value 
                      // ...
                     ,"Casted to an unsupported type!");
    }
    // ...
};

template<>
HybridType::operator std::uint16_t() const {
    return std::stoi(internalStr);
}

template<>
HybridType::operator std::uint32_t() const {
    return std::stoul(internalStr);
}

// aso. ...
```

Comment: Thank you, but i've another question: if i've to overload each operator for each return types, templates are useless for this case?

Comment: @Ayak973 _"Thank you, but i've another question:"_ Sure? Didn't my answer not explain completely what actually happens?

Comment: Not quite.  Templates will cause a compilation failure if you miss a case.  (The compiler will select the perfect match, and then find it doesn't know how to generate it.)  If you provide separate functions, the compiler will make best efforts to find a way to convert.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: Sure! Your answer is satisfying (for me, at least), but in this particular case templates offer nothing more for me than write non templated overloaded cast operator? Edit: Too slow for typing, i get my answer in comments

Comment: @Ayak973 Well, have a look at R. Sahu's answer. You could have a default implementation for the templated cast operator though, that bails out using a `std::static_assert` for unsupported types.

Comment: As @MartinBonner pointed out, i want a "templated cast operator with explicit specializations" to prevent integer overflow, and a compilation error. His answer was helpful too.

Comment: @Ayak973 Sure Martin's answer was helpful as well, as R Sahu's is. I never stated these aren't.  Note that Martin started a [discussion at Meta SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315587/combining-answers) about this. You don't actually need to accept a particular answer here, but if you choose mine, well OK ;-) ...

Comment: `static_assert(false,"Casted to an unsupported type!");` is ill-formed NDR. You need to make the `false` dependent.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you for the static_assert edit, your solution works well. Note: since i've only one header file, i'd have to `inline` the templates definition `template<> inline HybridType::operator uint16_t() const {}`

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is `operator T()`.  Look at it from the compiler's point of view.  If you expand for `uint32_t` you get:

```
operator uint32_t() const {
    if (...) return std::stoi(internalStr);
    if (...) return std::stoul(internalStr);
    if (...) return std::stoul(internalStr);
    if (...) return std::stod(internalStr);
    if (...) return std::stold(internalStr);   // Consider here
    if (...) return std::stof(internalStr);
    return std::stoll(internalStr);
}
```

Which looks to the compiler that you might be trying to return a long double from a function that is supposed to return `uint32_t`.  Of course, later on in the compilation process, that will get optimized down to:

```
operator uint32_t() const {
    return std::stoul(internalStr);
}
```

... but by that time, the warning has been issued.

The *fix* is either:

- Write each cast operator that you want explicitly.  (See [R Sahu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35044446/771073) for details.)  This has the advantage of being simpler and less typing.
- Write a templated cast operator declaration without a definition, and then write explicit specializations for each type that you want.  (See [πάντα ῥεῖ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35044180/771073) for details.)  This has the feature that you must create an operator for every type you want to be able tot cast too; a missing type will be a compilation error. This may be an advantage (more control on range etc), or a disadvantage (more code) depending on your application.

The advantage of the formwerapproach

Comment: That's why you'd use template specialization or tag dispatching, which are both selected at compile-time.

Comment: @black : What is your objection to including πάντα ῥεῖ 's code in this answer (with full attribution).  The OP needs both; an explanation of what is going wrong, and how to fix it.

Comment: (sorry, forgot to explain that in the edit summary) I wouldn't find it useful or nice to do; rather, if you really need to, say something like: "$user shows a solution to that". It's not a community answer.

Comment: (oh well, you already got a [better] answer on meta; more or less resembles my point)

Comment: @black: Thanks for the correction - a good learning opportunity for me.

Answer (score 2):

[The answer by Martin Booner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35044145/434551) has already pointed out the core issue. I am going to suggest a simpler solution for what you want to accomplish in your class.

Using templates for classes and functions is worthwhile only when the implementation is generic. That's not true in your case. The logic to return a `int` is different that logic to return a `double`. Using a member function template for this is not the best use of templates.

```
template<typename T>
operator T() const {
    if (std::is_same<T, std::uint16_t>::value) return std::stoi(internalStr);
    if (std::is_same<T, std::uint32_t>::value) return std::stoul(internalStr);
    if (std::is_same<T, std::uint64_t>::value) return std::stoul(internalStr);
    if (std::is_same<T, double>::value) return std::stod(internalStr);
    if (std::is_same<T, long double>::value) return std::stold(internalStr);
    if (std::is_same<T, float>::value) return std::stof(internalStr);
    return std::stoll(internalStr);
}
```

is not any simpler than:

```
operator std::uint16_t() const {
    return std::stoi(internalStr);
}

operator std::uint32_t() const {
    return std::stoul(internalStr);
}

operator std::uint64_t() const {
    return std::stoul(internalStr);
}

operator double() const {
    return std::stod(internalStr);
}

operator long double() const {
    return std::stold(internalStr);
}

operator float() const {
    return std::stof(internalStr);
}

operator long long() const {
    return std::stoll(internalStr);
}
```

even though the latter is more verbose due the presence of more functions.

Comment: The advantage of a templated cast operator with explicit specializations is that it will fail to compile if you write `int i = HybridType(....);`  Your version will call  `operator long long()` and then possibly cause undefined behaviour with integer overflow.

Comment: @MartinBonner, good point. FWIW, in my test, using `int i = ...` resolved to the `std::uint16_t` overload.